# vb.net arrays and or operator

Tags: arrays, vb.net, loops

```
temp = 0
count = 0

Do
    If arraywinner(count) = first(0) Or first(1) Or first(2) Or first(3) Or first(4) Or first(5) Then
        temp = temp + 1
    End If

    count = count + 1
Loop Until count > 5
```

This is my code... I'm trying to compare my array value with each value from another array and if there is the same number, the `temp` variable will be increment, but the problem here is that it's working. The value is 1 2 3 4 5 6 not what I'm expecting can someone help please

Comment: You can't compare a single value to lots of other values like that. You can do this: `If x = y Or z Then`. You must do this: `If x = y Or x = z Then`. Also, you should use `OrElse` rather than `Or`.

Comment: That is not valid code.  Simplify the expression by using a For-loop to step through the first() elements.

Comment: You can also do this: `If {y, z}.Contains(x) Then`.

Comment: `Or` is a bitwise operator, so you are comparing arraywinner(count) to the bitwise or of all of `first` from 0 to 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are four other methods. It depends on what code you feel comfortable with and how easy it is to read. They each produce the same results.

```
Private Sub FindMatch()
    Dim arraywinner() As Integer = {1, 4, 27, 39, 41, 46}
    Dim first() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
    'Method 1 a nested For
    'Using a For Each so the arrays can be any size
    For Each winner In arraywinner
        For Each f In first
            If f = winner Then
                MessageBox.Show($"Found {f} Winner (Using Nested For Each)")
            End If
        Next
    Next
    'Method 2 using .Contains 
    For Each winner In arraywinner
        If first.Contains(winner) Then
            MessageBox.Show($"Found a winner number {winner} (Using .Contains)")
        End If
    Next
    'Method 3 using .Intersect
    'Think of 2 circles containing the numbers in the arrays. Where they overlap would be the intersection.
    Dim Matches As IEnumerable(Of Integer) = arraywinner.Intersect(first)
    For Each i As Integer In Matches
        MessageBox.Show($"Winner Is {i} (Using Intersect)")
    Next
    'Method 4
    'The Linq query
    'From all the Integers in arraywinner
    'Where - set a condition - The first array contains i
    'Select - just the integers that meet the condition
    'LinqResult - contains just those integers
    'It is IEnumerable(Of Integer) 
    'IEnumerable means it can be accessed with a For Each
    Dim LinqResult = From i In arraywinner
                     Where first.Contains(i)
                     Select i
    For Each i In LinqResult
        MessageBox.Show($"Winner {i} (Using Linq Query")
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give the results you are seeking. 'OrElse' is used in place of the old 'Or' because it short-circuits the comparison, meaning the statement stops comparing after the first successful match. 'Or' in VB6 and earlier did not short-circuit, and VB.NET preserves that behavior to ease the task of migrating old code.

```
    Dim temp As Integer = 0
    Dim arraywinner() As Integer = New Integer(5) {1, 4, 27, 39, 41, 46}
    Dim first() As Integer = New Integer(5) {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}

    For count As Integer = 0 To 5
        If arraywinner(count) = first(0) _
            OrElse arraywinner(count) = first(1) _
            OrElse arraywinner(count) = first(2) _
            OrElse arraywinner(count) = first(3) _
            OrElse arraywinner(count) = first(4) _
            OrElse arraywinner(count) = first(5) Then
            temp = temp + 1
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Explain why you use OrElse.

Comment: And show an idiomatic .NET alternative - both for a single `count` ([`Contains`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54960206/vb-net-arrays-and-or-operator#comment96681795_54960206)) and for the entire thing (`from a in arraywinner where first.Contains(a)`).

Comment: This is the answer the OP asked for.